# React JS - How to update firestore values in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I have successfully change the value of a document variable inside my Firestore but it doesn't update visually (if that makes sense) as soon as I call the function it does update after a hard refresh or normal refresh.

This is how it looks in the table and in the Firestore:

Table render

[image]

Firestore

[image]

When I press the button it does change the value to +1 but it doesn't visually change until I refresh the page

[image]

and it does also changes in the Firestore

[image]

So I want to know if it is possible to do this in realtime because not only it doesn't update as soon as I press the button I can't press it more than once, if I press the button let's say 10 times it will still only do ++1 instead of ++1 (x10) this is the piece of code:

```js
const mas = (producto, quantity) => {
  const temporalQuery = db.collection('productosAIB').doc(producto);
  temporalQuery.update({
    cantidad: ++quantity
  })
};
```

And this is where is rendering and where the function is being called :

```
<tbody>
  {productos.map((productos, index) => (
    <tr key={productos.id || index}>
      <td>
        <button onClick={() => mas(productos.descripcion, productos.cantidad)} />
        {productos.cantidad}
        <button onClick={() => menos(productos.descripcion, productos.cantidad)} />
      </td>
      <td>{productos.grado}</td>

      <td >
        {productos.descripcion}
      </td>

      <td >${productos.precio}</td>
    </tr>
  ))
}
</tbody>
```

Bit that reads from firebase

```
const [productos, setProductos] = useState([]);
    const productosRef = db.collection('productosAIB');

    useEffect(() => {
        productosRef.orderBy('cantidad')
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) => {
              const tempData = [];
            snapshot.forEach((doc) => {

              const data = doc.data();
              tempData.push(data);
            });
            setProductos(tempData);
          });
      }, []);
```

if you require whole code let me know. It does the job but I just wanted to know if there was a way to make it render in real time.

Comment: FYI, `<button>` elements are not self closing

Comment: thank you for the information, still learning to code in React, can you tell me why is not a good practice ? (cause I have been using them like that for a while and haven't encounter issues yet)

Comment: They should look like `<button>Button content</button>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: This buttons do not have any content that's why I have them self closing all they do is call a function I do not want them to have any text or just anything.

Comment: None of the code you shared actually **reads** from Firestore. Can you add that code, which I assume sets `productos`?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm really sorry I though I did, Just added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `.get()` which [reads the documents from the database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data) just once. If you want to continue [listening for changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen), use `onSnapshot` instead:

```
useEffect(() => {
    productosRef.orderBy('cantidad')
    .onSnapshot()
    ...
```

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense, I was using a code that was working on a previous code but it wasn't using cantidad from firebase it was just a value from the code itself so I though it would be the same, thank you! I got it working